# Flexbox Image gallery and single image position

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, flexbox

From this image gallery, I want to keep the top right image position always the same, I tried to fix but I couldn't!

Here is the Reference for image gallery

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

img {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  /* IE10 */
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* IE10 */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.column {
  -ms-flex: 25%;
  /* IE10 */
  flex: 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.column img {
  margin-top: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#overlay:hover {
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .column {
    -ms-flex: 50%;
    flex: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}


/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    -ms-flex: 100%;
    flex: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>


  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/rocks.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/falls2.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/paris.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/nature.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/mist.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/paris.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/ocean.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/mountainskies.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/rocks.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/rocks.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/falls2.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/paris.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/nature.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/mist.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/paris.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/ocean.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/mountainskies.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/rocks.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, what do you mean "I want to keep the top right image position always the same" ? it's always there at top...

Comment: If you look at https://www.pexels.com/ leaderboard always the same position, I want to keep always the same position any one image!

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

img {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  /* IE10 */
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* IE10 */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.column {
  -ms-flex: 33.3%;
  /* IE10 */
  flex: 33.3%;
  max-width: 33.3%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.column img {
  margin-top: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#overlay:hover {
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .column {
    -ms-flex: 50%;
    flex: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}


/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    -ms-flex: 100%;
    flex: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column" style="flex: 100%; max-width: 100%;">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/rocks.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/falls2.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/paris.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/nature.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/mist.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/paris.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/ocean.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/mountainskies.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/rocks.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/rocks.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/falls2.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/paris.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/nature.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/mist.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/paris.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/ocean.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/mountainskies.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/rocks.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" id="overlay" style="width:100%"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

The image you wanted to keep on top just remove that from the `.row` and create another `.row > .column` then put the `img`

Hope it'll help

Comment: It will be similar like https://www.pexels.com/ layout and position will right top corner leaderboard/photographers image

Comment: I have reviewed the site. They didn't keep that fixed, just we've used `flex: 25%` instead they used `flex: 33.3%`. Also checked responsiveness, it was going down. Keep the same, updated the code. Please review

Comment: No ! Just I want to keep an image in `top right` position in every responsive layout!

Comment: You don't want to stack your layout?

Comment: Can you please describe exactly what you need?
You want two column on small devices? Or you want one image on top right as a sidebar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197197/discussion-between-momin-and-nazifa-rashid).